# Need help to target / modify custom data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a website/webshop in WordPress with Woocommerce and tries to add a quantity field next to the 'add to cart' button.

I found this article/tutorial: 
How to add quantity to product archives in WooCommerce (and keep ajax) - Christian Varga
http://christianvarga.com/how-to-add-quantity-to-product-archives-in-woocommerce-and-keep-ajax/

It got two small snippets - The first will work correct after copy/paste in my function.php file.
The second is some javascript code which will make the quantity field work together with the 'add to cart' button.

This is the code:

```
$('.input-text.qty', 'ul.products').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').next('a').attr('data-quantity', $(this).val());
});
```

When I insert the javascript code nothing happens. It is because I use a custom theme (Avada) which has a different structure I guess.

This was also written on the tutorial:

> *Note: This works with WooCommerce’s default HTML structure, but if you’re using a custom theme the HTML structure might be different, so
>   you’ll need to modify this script to suit.

Here is the link to my page:
http://frisk-matic.identitest.dk/kaffe/

I tried to target my 'add to cart' button but I cannot get it to work and I am not that skilled when it comes to Javascript.
Can someone help me? I would be so glad if I could get a little understanding how this code works.

I know that the first line is to select the quantity field we added and the products div and the result is to change the data-quantity attribute for the button.

Best regards
Samz3n

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
$('.input-text.qty').on('change', function() {
    $(this).parent().next('a.add_to_cart_button').attr('data-quantity', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work :( Thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your html markup is not the same with this template. I've inspected the markup and write some jQuery code. I think it will do the thing for you! :)

```
$('.quantity').find('input[type="number"]').on('change',function(){
    $(this).parent().next('.product-buttons').find('.add_to_cart_button').data('quantity',$(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Unfortunately your code won't work. The quantity is not send when you hit on the 'add to cart' button. Is it because that Avada use Ajax to add/send products to cart? I know that the html markup is not the same as a normal woocommerce store and tried multiple solutions :) Im very thankful for helping me

Comment: I think you need to find something here: http://frisk-matic.identitest.dk/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.min.js?ver=2.2.10 but i'm not too familiar with WordPress and its plugins because I use my custom framework.

Answer (score 0):

u might have some name collisions with your jQuery library, u can try this

```
var $ = jQuery;
$('.quantity').find('input[type="number"]').on('change', function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var button = $(this).parent().next('.product-buttons').find('.add_to_cart_button');
  button.attr('data-quantity', value);
});
```

or better, use this until you fix naming collisions with jQuery

```
jQuery('.quantity').find('input[type="number"]').on('change', function () {
  var value = jQuery(this).val();
  var button = jQuery(this).parent().next('.product-buttons').find('.add_to_cart_button');
  button.attr('data-quantity', value);
});
```